# Android Java List.get stops and doesn't return anything

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have a ListFragment and registered it for a context menu so that it will show a context menu on long clicking an item in the list.

I have one item in the list and when I click it for a few seconds, everything works fine and the context menu will appear. When I click on duplicate, it is supposed to perform an action.

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    //Display A Warning Before Removing A Playlist
    final int currentIndex = info.position;

    switch( item.getItemId() ) {
    case DUPLICATE_ID:
        duplicate( currentIndex ); //duplicate will be called
        return true; //we will never get to this point
    }

    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}

//method that will be called
private void duplicate( int index ) {

    DebugHelper.logDebug( "" + mItems.size() ); // returns 1 
    Playlist playlist = mItems.get( index ); //stops here

    playlist.setPlaylistID( playlistCollection.getMaximumID()+1 );

    //TODO:what if the file already exists?
    Playlist.savePlaylistToFile( AudioUtils.PLAYLIST_DIRECTORY , String.valueOf( playlist.getPlaylistID() ), playlist );

    playlistCollection.add(playlist);
    Storage.getInstance().getPlaylistCollection().add(playlist);

    //update list
    ((PlaylistListAdapter) getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

The `return true;` statement will never be called and the context menu stays on click. Duplicate will be called, however the line `mItems.get( index );` just stops. The debugger shows me a few classes and in the end stops in the Looper class which I cannot read.

`mItems` is not `null` and I don't receive any errors. The method works fine if I call it anywhere but in the `onContextItemSelected()`.

**Classes that will be accessed :**
AbsListView (no source)
Handler (no source)
Looper (no source and it stops right here)

Somewhere I saw something about main thread not suspended but I couldnt find it again.

Update :
I put `duplicate(0);` right after setting the list adapter for the ListFragmnent in the onCreate() method. It duplicated the first playlist AND I was able to click the context menu item now. However, I deleted all the playlists so that there is again only one item in the list and again it doesn't work....

Comment: so im sure that ArrayList.get() is the problem I just don't know why it works anywhere but in the context menu

Comment: It's difficult to answer this question without knowing what mItems is or where it comes from.